# How to fix invalid file format in Advanced Installer

Tags: advanced-installer

Today, I wanted to create a Setup file for Project in VS Community 2017. When I import file .sln in Advanced Installer 11.1. I receive notification from Advanced Installer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Latest Version***: Not my exertise, but off the top of my head: `1)`The first thing you might want to do is to download the latest version of Advanced Installer (15.0.1 at the time of writing), to see if this solves the whole problem.

***Language Issue?***: If that doesn't solve things (which it just might do), then `2)` I suppose this may have to do with the language. It looks like you have a Vietnamese VS project? That Advanced Installer project you show is set to "English" (look at title bar - it says "English US").  Maybe check the view "Translations". It does not look like Vietnamese is one of the supported, built-in languages for Advanced Installer (as of now). Towards the top right, select "All" in the "Show" box and select Vietnamese.

***Path Issue?***: `3)` Perhaps also try to copy the VS project to a path which does not have Vietnamese character in the file and path name? Then try to run the import again.

***VS Project Issue?***: `4)` Perhaps there are weird characters inside the VS Project that cause the problems? I guess there certainly are characters in there that are not normal, Western characters in your case.

***Advanced Installer Community***: That was just a couple of thoughts off the top of my head - essentially all about language and encoding, there could obviously be further issues. Also reminding you of the [**Advanced Installer Community Forums**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/). Please try your luck there if you don't get any good answers here.

---

***Some Links***:

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can we ask what the actual fix was? The newest version?

Comment: Yes, I did download and setup newest version of Advanced Installer

Comment: And I thing. Old version not support Vietnamese in path name